# compareAndSet() does not work as expected

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

I wrote my own **AtomicDouble** class and I also have a BankAccount class that does two simple withdrawals and deposits operations and it has an AtomicDouble instance(balance). The problem with my code is that when I call the **addAndGet** method in deposit(), the program falls into an infinite loop, and **compareAndSet**() never returns the true value, but when I debugged this, currentValue and the value from atomic.get () were equal, but this method does not understand.

The interesting thing is that when I put if (atomic.get()==currentValue) **instead of** if (atomic.compareAndSet(currentValue, nextValue)), the program runs properly.

```
public class AtomicDouble extends Number {

private final AtomicReference<Double> atomic;

public AtomicDouble() {
    this(0.0);
}

public AtomicDouble(double initialValue) {
    atomic = new AtomicReference<>(initialValue);
}

public final double addAndGet(double delta) {
    while (true) {
        double currentValue = atomic.get();
        double nextValue = currentValue + delta;
        if (atomic.compareAndSet(currentValue, nextValue))
            return nextValue;
    }
}

public final double incrementAndGet() {
    return addAndGet(1);
}

public final void set(double newValue) {
    atomic.set(newValue);
}

public final double get() {
    return atomic.get();
}


public final double getAndSet(double newValue) {
    return atomic.getAndSet(newValue);
}


public float floatValue() {
    return (float) get();
}

@Override
public double doubleValue() {
    return get();
}

public int intValue() {
    return (int) get();
}

public long longValue() {
    return (long) get();
}

public String toString() {
    return Double.toString(get());
}
```

}

```
public class BankAccount {
private final AtomicDouble balance;
private String accountNumber;

public BankAccount(double balance, String accountNumber) {
    this.balance = new AtomicDouble(balance);
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;

}

public void deposit(double number, String color) {
    System.out.println(color + "deposit  " + number + " current balance=" + balance.addAndGet(number));
}

public void withdraw(double number, String color) {
    if (this.balance.get() - number >= 0) {
        System.out.println(color + "Withdraw " + number + " current balance=" + balance.addAndGet(-number));
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(color + "Not enough balance");
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(1000.0, "4234236");

    ExecutorService threadsPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    threadsPool.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bankAccount.deposit(300.0, ThreadColor.ANSI_YELLOW);
            bankAccount.withdraw(50.0, ThreadColor.ANSI_YELLOW);
        }
    });

    threadsPool.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bankAccount.deposit(203.75, ThreadColor.ANSI_BLUE);
            bankAccount.withdraw(100.0, ThreadColor.ANSI_BLUE);
        }
    });

    threadsPool.shutdown();
}
```

}

**output**: There is no output

Comment: Normally bank accounts are tracked as a log of transactions, not as a mutable balance. I don't know what this project is for, but if it is for anything other than testing out your atomic double class, I'd reconsider how you store your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suppose it is because of autoboxing. You can't have a reference to `double`, you have a reference to `Double`.

The operands get "reboxed" each time around the loop and therefore references are never identical.   That is, the reference in `currentValue` is never the same as the reference in `atomic`.

Try using `currentValue` reference types.

```
public final double addAndGet(double delta) {
    while (true) {
        Double currentValue = atomic.get();
        Double nextValue = currentValue + delta;
        if (atomic.compareAndSet(currentValue, nextValue))
            return nextValue;
    }
}
```

(Fortunately, Double is an immutable type, otherwise this would have a race hazard)

Comment: That's right, but why doesn't unboxing occur? does not the unboxing occur when we assign a reference variable to a primitive variable? for example System.out.println(new Double(2.0)==2.0); prints true.

Comment: Yes - so unboxing is taking place in `currentValue + delta`.  And that sum is then boxed prior to assignment to `nextValue`.  But that does not matter; what matters is that the reference in `currentValue` is (when there is no collsiion on updating) the same as the reference inside the `AtomicReference`, so that the compareAndSet has a chance of succeeding.  `nextValue` could still be a primitive double but it looked cleaner the way I wrote it).

Comment: The idiomatic solution is to use an `AtomicLong` and convert using `Double.doubleToRawLongBits(…)` and `Double.longBitsToDouble(…)`